# im fairly new and facing a problem about sending api request

Tags: swift, api, post

I'm fairly new to the swift and I'm facing a problem with Alamofire what I'm trying to do is sending a get request with json body but I'm stuck heres my code:

```
    struct request {
    func getMessage(message:String){
    let parameters: [String:Any] =  [
        "message" : [
            "text": message,
            "type":"text"
        ],
        "type":"message",
        "recipentId":"",
        "info": [
            "token":""
        ]
    ]
        makeRequest(parameters: parameters)

}
    func makeRequest(parameters:[String:Any]){
        AF.request("https://bot.ortus4c.com/api/botController/token/5cc1f42e66d0ba0001dbf944",method: .post,parameters: parameters).response{
            response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
    }
```

after executing this code i get:

```
 [Request]: POST https://bot.ortus4c.com/api/botController/token/5cc1f42e66d0ba0001dbf944
[Request Body]: 
info%5Btoken%5D=&message%5Btype%5D=text&message%5Btext%5D=Karakter&recipentId=&type=message
[Response]: 
[Status Code]: 415
[Headers]:
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 07 Mar 2020 19:10:23 GMT
Server: cloudflare
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 57069dc3eaccad06-OTP
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
x-b3-traceid: b10ba988c0249901
[Response Body]: 
None
[Data]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.3303520679473877s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(nil)
```

i dont get any result body compared to what expect when i send this request over postman:

```
"result": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Karakter Analizine Hoşgeldiniz. Analize başlamak için \"karakter\" yazınız"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Test"
            }
        ],
        "tag": [
            "start",
            "finish"
        ],
        "conversation_id": "5e63f302dc4bec0001883f01",
        "intent_name": "Default Karakter",
        "intent_id": "5ccb46ef66d0ba0001dbfcdf",
        "intent_score": null,
        "current_flow_id": "ee52db21-dae1-4587-80cd-7649798dddce1583608578222"
    }
```

so how can i send this post request with this given body below:

```
let parameters: [String:Any] =  [
            "message" : [
                "text": message,
                "type":"text"
            ],
            "type":"message",
            "recipentId":"",
            "info": [
                "token":""
            ]
        ]
```

Now i have sent the request and got a body looking like this:

```
"result": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "extra": {},
                "question": "Adınız ?",
                "type": "text",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": ""
                    }
                ],
                "askCount": 1,
                "text": "Adınız ?",
                "waitUserInput": true
            }
        ],
        "tag": [
            "start",
            "p_firstName",
            1
        ],
        "conversation_id": "5e63ffa0dc4bec0001883f10",
        "intent_name": "Karakter Analizi",
        "intent_id": "5cc20ae266d0ba0001dbf946",
        "intent_score": "62.0",
        "current_flow_id": "62ac3ac8-0cd7-43e5-b92b-f119d49c40d41583611808850"
    }
```

how can i print the question variable to a label on my screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response code 415 means `Unsupported Media Type` and the `Accept` header of the response lets you know that the sever expects data to be sent as `JSON`. All you have to do is to let Alamofire know that it should encode parameters as `JSON` in the request body

```
AF.request("https://bot.ortus4c.com/api/botController/token/5cc1f42e66d0ba0001dbf944",
           method: .post,
           parameters: parameters, 
           encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: ive done it and got a code 500 i guess that means server error does that mean did i did something wrong or api just doesnt respond ?

Comment: No, code 500 is always server-side error. You should contact whomever is responsible for the API you're using.

Comment: can you also answer how can i print question parameter to a label ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the encoding type as well while sending request. since your parameters data is json add encoding parameter as **encoding: JSONEncoding.default**

for example i have used as:

```
manager.request(url, method: httpMethod,
                        parameters: parameters,
                        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                        headers: configuredHeader)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { [weak self] response in
                self?.handleNetworkResponse(response: response, networkCompletionHandler: networkCompletionHandler)
            })
```